# How to transform a subsequence?

Tags: python, iterator, generator

Suppose I have a function which takes one generator and produces a new one. For example, `pair(gen)` which converts a sequence `1, 2, 3, 4, ...` into `(1, 2), (3, 4), ...`.

Now I want to take a generator of some sequence and apply the transformation to its subsequence, while leaving other elements as they are. For example, if `gen` generates the sequence `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...` and I want to run `pair` on the even elements, then `withEven(gen, pair)` would produce `1, 3, (2, 4), 5, ...`. It should know how many elements `pair` will need nor should it cache all the odd numbers received until pair yields. It should get the next item from main sequence, if it's odd, yield it, if it's even, feed it to the transformer and repeat.

**Is `withEven` possible to define?**

If `pair` is defined as

```
def pair(gen):
  prev = None
  for x in gen:
    if prev:
      yield (prev, x)
      prev = None
    else:
      prev = x
```

Then a `withEvenRunPair(gen)`, equivalent to `withEven(gen, pair)`, is trivial to define as

```
def withEvenRunPair(gen):
  prev = None
  for x in gen:
    if x % 2 == 1:
      yield x
    else:
      if prev:
        yield (prev, x)
        prev = None
      else:
        prev = x
```

However defining a generic `withEven` seems more difficult.

Comment: the issue here I think is to know where to insert the result yielded by `pair`. You would probably create a generator that feeds the even values to `pair`, and iterate on `gen`, pushing values either to the output or to the first generator (which would be a queue, hence), depending on when they are odd or even. There is probably something to do with testing if `pair` is ready to yield an output.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can do something like this:

```
from itertools import islice, izip, izip_longest, tee

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    # https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)

def withEvenRunPair(gen):
    it1, it2 = tee(gen)
    odd = islice(it1, 0, None, 2)
    even = islice(it2, 1, None, 2)
    for a, b in izip_longest(grouper(odd, 2), grouper(even, 2)):
        yield a
        yield b


gen = (x for x in xrange(1, 13))
for x in withEvenRunPair(gen):
    print x
```

**Output:**

```
(1, 3)
(2, 4)
(5, 7)
(6, 8)
(9, 11)
(10, 12)
```

Comment: No, I can write pair and `withEvenRunPair` no matter how fancy. What I want is a generic `withEven` (or `withSelector`) which would take a generator and a transformation (pair was just an example) and apply the transformation to part of the generated items.

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė Can you re-explain the question? Perhaps provide better examples.

Comment: I have trouble understanding what the problem is. Though there is obviously a problem... What I want is to split `withEvenRunPair` into two functions, `withEven` and `pair`, such that I could apply `withEven` to any other transformation like `triple` (which transforms 1, 2, 3, ... -> (1, 2, 3), ...) or `onesAndZeros` (which transforms 1, 2, 3 ... -> 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0) or whatever I come up with. Writing `withEvenRunOnesAndZeros` seems easy, but separating the functions seems hard.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like?

```
def pair(sequence, selector=bool, fill=None, error_on_fill=False):
    sentinel = object()
    previous = sentinel
    for item in sequence:
        if not selector(item):
            yield item
            continue
        if previous is not sentinel:
            yield previous, item
            previous = sentinel
        else:
            previous = item

    if previous is not sentinel:
        if error_on_fill:
            raise ValueError("Final selected item missing a paired valued")
        yield previous, fill

result = list(pair(range(10), selector=(lambda x: x % 2 == 0)))
assert result == [1, (0, 2), 3, 5, (4, 6), 7, 9, (8, None)]
```

Comment: No, I can write `pair` and `withEvenRunPair` no matter how fancy. What I want is a generic `withEven` (or `withSelector`) which would take a generator and a transformation (`pair` was just an example) and apply the transformation to part of the generated items.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out, although it requires some changes to `pair` and other transformations.

The only way to stop a computation and later resume it is to `yield`. Therefore if we replace `input_generator.next()` with a `yield` of some sort, we can control the pace at which values are fed to the transformation.

First I define a request object

```
class Get(object):
  def isset(self):
    return hasattr(self, 'value')

  def set(self, x):
    self.value = x
```

I will now replace `n = foo.next()` with

```
g = Get()
yield g
if not g.isset():
  break
n = g.value
```

For example the `pair` from my question would become

```
def pair(): #notice that there isn't an input generator any more
  prev = None
  while True: #there was a next() hidden inside 'for'
    g = Get()
    yield g
    if not g.isset():
      break
    elif prev:
      yield (prev, g.value)
      prev = None
    else:
      prev = g.value
```

This kind of transformation can be easily turned into a proper transformation

```
def withGen(fn, gen):
  for f in fn: #get the next request or result
    if isinstance(f, Get):
      f.set(gen.next()) #answer requests with gen.next()
    else:
      yield f  #yield results

print [x for x in withGen(pair(), [1, 2, 3, 4].__iter__())]
#prints [(1, 2), (3, 4)]
```

Finally we can define `withSelector`

```
def withSelector(select, fn):
  f = None #we need to remember the last unanswered request
  while True:
    if not f: #if last request has been answered...
      f = fn.next() #get the next request, or the result

    if isinstance(f, Get): #if it's a request...
      g = Get()
      yield g #ask for another input value
      if not g.isset():
        break
      elif select(g.value): #if the values matches selector...
        f.set(g.value) #feed it to transformation
        f = None #and mark the request as answered
      else:
        yield g.value #otherwise just yield it

    else: #if transformation yielded a result
      yield f #yield it
      f = None #and note that there is no request waiting

arr = range(1, 18)
print [x for x in withGen(withSelector(isEven, pair()), arr.__iter__())]
#prints [1, 3, (2, 4), 5, 7, (6, 8), 9, 11, (10, 12), 13, 15, (14, 16), 17]
```

I can even sequence two selectors. For example, If I defined `add3` to `yield` three `Get()`s and then `yield` the sum of their results, I could

```
print [x for x in withGen(withSelector(isOdd, add3()), withGen(withSelector(isEven, pair()), arr.__iter__()))]
#prints [(2, 4), 9, (6, 8), 27, (10, 12), (14, 16), 45]
```